# Is there a way to listen to mouse event in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I want to write a script that runs a specific PowerShell command when one of my mouse's additional buttons is clicked.

**Example:** Clicking the third mouse's button will run `echo "…"` PowerShell command.

But I'm not sure what's the best way to listen to this kind of the OS events.
Please advice.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer, and does it do what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44659421/4190564

Comment: Thank you, Darin.
It was helpful but I just found this resources which does exactly what I want.
You just need to change WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 14 to listen to mouse events.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this resourcet to be super useful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c

You just need to change `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` value to be 14 to start listening to mouse events.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites without first putting the salient content in the answer itself. Would this answer be valuable if the link got broken?